# Which ColorFunction was used for this ListDensityPlot?

Tags: plotting, graphics, color

I want to reproduce the plot below with `ListDensityPlot`, but I don't know which `ColorFunction` to choose.

Can you help me figure out the correct `ColorFunction`?

[image: figure]

Comment: It looks like ColorData["TemperatureMap"]

Comment: Or you can use `Blend` to make your homebrew color bar

Comment: @Harry, Could you please say more about blend options for the colors in figure?

Comment: `Blend` is a function used to make color function, not an option itself. Use some software to pick up the color RGB number in your example, then you may try something like `ColorFunction -> (Blend[{RGBColor[{0.4, 0.4, 0.8}], White,  RGBColor[{.9, 0.4, 0.4}]}, #/1.5] &)` .

Answer (score 8):

[image]

It might be `ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"]`

But even if it is not built-in, you can get this ColorFunction right from your image. Import image, trim, remove transparency:

```
i=RemoveAlphaChannel@ImageTrim[
Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/nX62j.png"],
{{50,50},{340,280}}];
```

Get the DominantColors:

```
col = DominantColors[i, 5]
```

[image]

Sort according to some metric

```
colSort=SortBy[col,ColorDistance[col[[1]],#,DistanceFunction->"CIE76"]&]
```

[image]

Construct ColorFunction and check if it is what you want:

```
colFun=Blend[colSort,#]&;
colFun/@Range[0,1,.05]//Row
```

[image]

Use it in various plotting functions:

```
DensityPlot[Arg[Sin[x+I*y]^3/(x+I*y+1)^4],{x,0,5},{y,0,5},
ColorFunction->colFun,PlotPoints->50,PlotLegends->Placed[Automatic, Below]]

ContourPlot[y+Sin[x^2+3y],{x,-3.5,3.5},{y,-3.5,3.5},
ColorFunction->colFun,PlotLegends->Placed[Automatic, Below]]
```

[image]